# How to output an excel array without knowing how many items it has

Tags: vba, excel, array-formulas

**Scenario:** I have a code that connects to an API (in this case Factset) and retrieves some data. The data output of the formula is an array of dates, which can have any number of dates inside.

**Issue:** Currently, my code puts the formula into the sheets and updates. The problem is, for an excel array to work (as far as I understand), I have to select as many cells as output items and press "ctrl+shift+enter". The problem is, for each item in my list, I don't know precisely how many output values will be, so I cannot pre-select that range, therefore my output just get the first data row of the array.

For example, the output should be:

```
15.01.2018
15.02.2018
15.03.2018
15.04.2018
15.05.2018
```

but since I don't know there will be 5 dates for that item, my current output is only:

```
15.01.2018
```

**Question:** Is there a possible way to do this, without having the final number of data rows that will be in the output? If so, how could I do it?

**Code so far:**

```
For i = 2 To numberofitems + 1
    If wb.Worksheets("Dates").Cells(1, i).Value <> "" Then
        wb.Worksheets("Call Prices").Cells(2, i).Formula = "=FDS(" & Cells(1, i).Address(0, 0) & ",""FI_(CALL,,DATE,,DATE)"")"
        Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dates").Cells(2, i)
        Application.SendKeys("^+{ENTER}")    
    End If
Next i
```

**Obs:** I also read some other posts with the .FormulaArray property, but could not understand how to use it without preselecting the range.

Obs2: The data is retrieved form the API (factset), so it is neither on the sheet nor in a VBA array. Since the data will come from the API, I don't know beforehand how many items it will have.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your `Dates` sheet?

Comment: If the data is in Excel, the are VBA methods for finding the last cell with data. If the data is in an array in VBA, you can use the `UBound(array,1)-LBound(array,1)` to find the size of the array.

Comment: @Zac On that sheets there is only a series of identifiers in the first row, which are sent to the API.

Comment: @Mistella the data is in neither. It uses the identifiers in the sheet to get data from the API (factset).

Comment: When API returns the data, where is that data stored?

Comment: @Zac it is pasted directly to the worksheet, in any selected cell. If only one cell is selected, only one item of the array appears. If 2 cells are selected, 2 items appear, and so on.

Comment: Could you not use `UsedRange` to find out how many cells are populated in `the sheet`?

Comment: @Zac So far I could get 2 different outputs: if I go into the API and insert the formula, then it will past properly, all items included. If I run it from vba, just acessing the API, it will only past 1 cell, because that is what my macro is configured to select. I tried UsedRange also, but it shows shows the row with the formula is used, nothing more.

Comment: Could you show an example function call with the actual values, not cell references please? Perhaps the one that generated your 5 dates shown at the top.

Comment: @QHarr the value in B1 is "US09069NAF50"

Comment: The formula array you are referring is `=FDS(" & Cells(1, i).Address(0, 0) & ",""FI_(CALL,,DATE,,DATE)"")`? It's entered in worksheet `Call Prices`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the dates into an array and then loop through each of the items in the array.

```
Sub datesArray()
   vDates As Variant

   vDates = Sheets("Sheets1").Range("A1:A5")

   For i = 1 To UBound(vDates)
    'your code
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't have the initial  dates for every item, it comes from the API, so I could not pass it to an array.